# Can I determine where content came from?

Tags: support, android-app, ios-app, api, stackapps

The [API documentation states](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write):

> The application responsible for creating content via the API may be indicated with a link to an app's Stack Apps post. The exact manner of display is subject to change at any time.
>
> For example, API created comments current look like the following when hovered over:
>
> [image: example]

Does anything like this exist anymore?

Comment: I do remember seeing this for a short time, but I believe they removed it because it was just clutter at the end of comments that no one really cared about. I remember it being pretty annoying.

Comment: It could yet be brought back on-hover.  Should I retag as [tag:discussion] or [tag:feature-request], or should it stay as-is?